# How to use starts-with() in xpath to switch to frame using Selenium

Tags: python, java, selenium, xpath, startswith

Can anyone help me understand how i use the following java code in python and selenium:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath("//iframe[starts-with(@name, 'a-') and starts-with(@src, 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha')]"))); 
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("div.recaptcha-checkbox-checkmark"))).click();
```

I tried using string formatting and couldnt find a way of using `starts-with()` in python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*`starts-with()`* is a [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) function used for finding the web element whose attribute value gets changed on refresh or by other dynamic operations on the webpage. It should remain identical irrespective of the language binding e.g. *Java*, *Python*, *C#*, etc.

---

The equivalent of the following *Java* based lines of code:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath("//iframe[starts-with(@name, 'a-') and starts-with(@src, 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha')]"))); 
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("div.recaptcha-checkbox-checkmark"))).click();
```

in *Python* would be as follows:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[starts-with(@name, 'a-') and starts-with(@src, 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha')]")))
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.recaptcha-checkbox-checkmark"))).click()
```

Comment: i am unable to get it to work with the site i am trying to enter into the captcha on here is the html : https://i.imgur.com/Azh9D5Q.png help would be appreciated this is my code: https://i.imgur.com/5A7zxU0.png

Comment: _trying to enter into the captcha_: Sounds to be a different question all together. Feel free to raise a new question as per your new requirement.

Comment: No its not i want to just click the captcha and have it semi automated but allow me to click the images